# Printing parsed data from a csv file to a new file

Tags: python, csv

I am using Python to parse data from the following `csv` file -

```
{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},1,U0.00 - Sensor1 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12

{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},2,U0.01 - Sensor2 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12

{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},3,U0.02 - \n,1,0,12

{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},4,U0.03 - Sensor4 Not Ready\nTry Again,1,0,12

{::[name]str1_str2_str3[0]},5,U0.04 - \n,1,0,12
```

From the column1, I am parsing the value `0` within the `[ ]`. Then the value in column2 and from column3, I am parsing the substring "`Sensor1 Not Ready`" and then printing to another file as follows -

```
SENSOR1_NOT_READY 0,1
SENSOR2_NOT_READY 0,2
```

and so on...

Now when I print the parsed values I get the following -

```
SENSOR1_NOT_READY 0,1
SENSOR2_NOT_READY 0,2
SENSOR2_NOT_READY 0,3
SENSOR4_NOT_READY 0,4
SENSOR4_NOT_READY 0,5
```

I want to skip printing the lines with no data in column3 (for example - lines `3` and `5` in the `csv` file). How should I do that?

Expected output -

```
SENSOR1_NOT_READY 0,1
SENSOR2_NOT_READY 0,2
SENSOR4_NOT_READY 0,4
```

Following is my Python script -

```
with open('filename.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        tag_name = row[0]
        bit_num = row[1]
        error_name = row[2]

        # Regular expressions
        term0 = '\[(\d)\].*'
        term1 = '(\d+)'
        term2 = r'.*-\s([\w\s]+)\\n'

        capture0 = list(re.search(term0, tag_name).groups())
        capture1 = list(re.search(term1, bit_num).groups())
        temp = re.search(term2, error_name)
        if temp:
            result = list(temp.groups())
        else:
            None
        result[-1] = '_'.join(result[-1].split()).upper()
        capture2 = ','.join(result)

        tp = (capture0[0], capture1[0], capture2) # Tuple
        f.write('{2} {0},{1},\n'.format(tp[0], tp[1], tp[2]))
```

Comment: why not do something like:  if  'Sensor' in row: DO STUFF else: take a nap

Answer (score 0):

Build a regex that searches for 'normal' lines. Maybe something like `"^U0.0[1-5] - \n$"`? Then use something like `if not re.search(x):` before you print the error.

```
with open('filename.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        tag_name = row[0]
        bit_num = row[1]
        error_name = row[2]

        # Regular expressions
        term0 = '\[(\d)\].*'
        term1 = '(\d+)'
        term2 = r'.*-\s([\w\s]+)\\n'
        term3 = '^U0.0[1-5] - \n$'

        capture0 = list(re.search(term0, tag_name).groups())
        capture1 = list(re.search(term1, bit_num).groups())
        temp = re.search(term2, error_name)
        if temp:
            result = list(temp.groups())
        else:
            None
        result[-1] = '_'.join(result[-1].split()).upper()
        capture2 = ','.join(result)

        tp = (capture0[0], capture1[0], capture2) # Tuple
        if not re.search(temp3,error_name):
            f.write('{2} {0},{1},\n'.format(tp[0], tp[1], tp[2])) #I assume this is the print line?
```

Comment: I have made an update in the initial post, the `U0.00` updates in every line and is not the same in every line. I apologize for the typo

Comment: It's still trivial to regex out.

Comment: And it's the technique that's important, not the exact code.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help.